# SQL Moving window over two level of groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table of orders for users like the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id    UUID,
    user_id     UUID,
    date        date,
    order_type  integer
);
```

I want to write SQL to do the following:

- For every order want to compute the number of orders the user has within a previous week (7 days).
  [image]

Write the following, but it counts the number of orders for each user but not for two levels of groupby.

```
SELECT order_id, user_id,
   COUNT(order_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as num_orders_7days

FROM orders
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `RANGE` clause instead of `ROWS` with the proper date intervals:

```
SELECT order_id, user_id, date,
       COUNT(order_id) OVER (
         PARTITION BY user_id 
         ORDER BY date 
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 day PRECEDING AND INTERVAL 1 day PRECEDING
       ) as num_orders_7days
FROM orders;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d2d490aa02eba9f31881f0b477c1a4e).

Comment: Thanks! but what is the difference here between rows and range?

Comment: @H.H take your sample data for example: `ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` for user u1 and date 2019-12-16, covers all 7 previous rows (and the current row) without checking the values of the dates of these rows. But, RANGE creates a window with only the dates that are between the bounds defined: between date - INTERVAL 7 day AND date - INTERVAL 1 day.

Comment: @H.H as it is your requirement, without any filtering (say for a specific user), the query needs a full table scan. Indexes on user_id and date may help for the window function.